# easy_install error "No local packages or download links found for python-pack==1.5.0beta2"

Tags: python, easy-install

I was trying to install a package using easy_install, errors happened "processing dependencies", looks like it cannot locate a package, here's the error I got

---

```
Processing dependencies for python-pack==1.5.0beta2
Searching for python-pack==1.5.0beta2
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/python-pack/
Couldn't find index page for 'python-pack' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for python-pack==1.5.0beta2
Best match: None
```

---

The package to be installed is actually for Ubuntu, and my system is Debian. But I didn't expect errors at this stage.

Could any one please help me out?

Thanks,

Zhihui

Answer (score 1):

Going to http://pypi.python.org/simple/python-pack/ shows that this package isn't available.
It's too bad, you may need to contact your package developer or scour the website where you got it from to find out what this dependency actually is.

Can you let us know where you got the package from?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem make sure you have easy install and run cmd as admin then type easy_install django hit enter this solves my issue hope it work for you too.
(I was using Windows)

Comment: Please explain your answer clearly, using sentences.

Answer (score 1):

should

http://pypi.python.org/simple/python-pack/

become

https://pypi.python.org/simple/python-pack/

locally first before you can even begin to get the package